# Save Rscript in Rmd format

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have R script.

```
mydat=read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/test.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
View(mydat)
str(mydat)

#deleted after FS
mydat$symboling.<-NULL
mydat$make.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL
mydat$fuel.type.<-NULL
mydat$aspiration.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL

#this vars have  small num. of obs.
mydat$engine.type.<-NULL
mydat$engine.location.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.doors.<-NULL 
mydat=na.omit(mydat)

#Feature Selection
FS=Boruta(normalized.losses.~.,data=mydat)
getSelectedAttributes(FS, withTentative = F)
plot(FS, cex.axis=0.5)

#get scatterplot
scatter.smooth(x=mydat$length.,y=mydat$normalized.losses.,main="normalized losse~length")


#split sample on train and sample
index <- sample(1:nrow(mydat),round(0.70*nrow(mydat)))
train <- mydat[index,]
test <- mydat[-index,]
```

I have to save it in Rmarkdown format (html).
Of course in Rstudio i can do that:
file-new file-rmarkdown-HTML

and i get this script

````
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

I don't want manually write this prefix ```{r}.
Is it possible to make  that those parts of the code that are separated by comments

```
#

#
```

were saved in rmarkdown format?
In output i expect for example

````
```{r}
mydat$symboling.<-NULL
mydat$make.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL
mydat$fuel.type.<-NULL
mydat$aspiration.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `spin()` function from the `knitr` package.
It will produce an `.md` file (but you can keep the intermediate `.Rmd` with the `precious = TRUE` argument), using the '#' chracter as the 'documentation argument:

> **doc** 
>   A regular expression to identify the documentation lines; by default it follows the roxygen convention, but it can be customized, e.g. if you want to use ## to denote documentation, you can use '^##\s*'.

For example:

```
spin('test.R', precious = TRUE, doc = '#')
```

produces:

#### test.Rmd

````
```{r }
mydat=read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/test.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
View(mydat)
str(mydat)
```

deleted after FS

```{r }
mydat$symboling.<-NULL
mydat$make.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL
mydat$fuel.type.<-NULL
mydat$aspiration.<-NULL
mydat$num.of.cylinders.<-NULL
```

this vars have  small num. of obs.
...
````

#### test.md

````
```r
mydat=read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/test.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
```

```
## Warning in file(file, "rt"): cannot open file 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/
## test.csv': No such file or directory
```

```
## Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
```

```r
View(mydat)
```
...
````

You may also have a look at the `stitch()` function and sibilings (`stitch_rhtml` and `stitch_rmd`), have a look [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/)